# Bootstrap button on-click event

Tags: button, onclick, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, buttonclick

How does one code a bootstrap button to open a modal when you click the button? Do I need JavaScript and where do I put it?

This is a copy of my code currently which is not working:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#myModal">Search Date/Time Select</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" bootstrap-toggle-modal="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!--Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Date/Time Select</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: [Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)... It's just `data-toggle="modal"`.. and yes, [Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery and popper.js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need Javascript to achieve this functionality. Specifically, jQuery and Popper.js. BootStrap has many other JavaScript plugins too.

If this is not working for you please check your index.html is set up correctly as per the  [getting started documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code does what you are asking as per the [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I would not recommend it, but if you desire to use an earlier release:

[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

[Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: I actual coped ad paste the above code into my index and it faded but the hold page plus the popup was modal.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are saying with the above? The second code snippet I have provided gives you a button that when clicked opens a modal, is this what you were asking for initially? My suggestion would be to read through the Bootstrap 4 documentation carefully.